# Nature of The Roots of The Quadratic Equation $(a-1)x^2+(4a-2)x+4a+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

For which values of the real parameter $a$ are the roots of the quadratic equation: 
$$
(a-1)x^2+(4a-2)x+4a+1=0
$$
a) Real

b) Positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(a−1)x^2+(4a−2)x+4a+1=0$ = 0

Given $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$

if $b^2 - 4ac < 0$ the roots are complex.

if $b^2 - 4ac = 0$ the roots are real and equal

if $b^2 - 4ac > 0$ the roots are real and distinct.

For real roots, Equating with the quadratic formula and substituting into if $b^2 - 4ac $
We have $(4a-2)^2-4(a-2)(4a+1) \geq 0$ which gives $-4a+8 \geq 0$ , which means $a \leq 2$

For positive roots you must solve $(-(4a-2) + \sqrt{-4a+8} ) / (2a-2)> 0 $ and $(-(4a-2) - \sqrt{-4a+8} )/ (2a-2) > 0 $ and the answer would be the intervals that overlap.

Answer (score 3):

The discriminant is
$$\Delta=(4a-2)^2-4(a-1)(4a+1)$$

a) For which values of $a$ is $\Delta$ non-negative?

b) For which values of $a$ is $\displaystyle \frac{2-4a-\sqrt{\Delta}}{a-1}>0$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, one thing I don't get though, how did you come up with the solution b), why is this a condition for the roots to be positive?

Comment: I just changed something. The reasoning comes from the quadratic formula, which gives the roots of a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ as $\displaystyle \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. In your case, $a=a-1$, $b=4a-2$, and $c=4a+1$.

Comment: Well this is of the sign of the smallest root as $\sqrt{\Delta}>0$ (of the sign only as a a $\frac{1}{2}$ factor is missing). So if it's positive, both are.

Comment: Yes, thanks, so for the roots to be non-negative/real the discriminant just has to be greater than or equal to 0, and for them to be positive the expression for calculating the roots just has to be greater than 0. I thought you had to use
Vieta's formulas or something like that.

Comment: Also, for one to argue that $\displaystyle \frac{2-4a-\sqrt{\Delta}}{a-1}>0$ can you just say that f(a)/g(a)>0 therefore only f(a)>0 ?